# How do I use share() on a relay?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a `behaviourRelay` that I would like to share between two subscriptions:

```
var firmwareVersionRelay = BehaviorRelay<FirmwareVersionModel?>(value: nil).share()
```

This, however, turns the relay into an `observable`, which means that I can no longer use the `accept` operator.

So how do I get around this? Is it possible to have a relay with share? Should I simply skipp share? Or should I just use `onNext` instead of `accept`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `share()` on a relay in order to share it.

Remember:

> Subjects provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use.
> -- [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#KeyTypes)

When an Observable is created (see the `create` operator), it is handed a closure that is called every time the Observable is subscribed to. This closure is expected to perform some sort of side effect and emit events.

If you only want that side effect to be performed once but you want to subscribe to it multiple times, you use the `share()` operator which *doesn't* subscribe to its source Observable every time it is subscribed to.

In the case of a subject (or relay which is a special kind of subject), there is no closure to call. A subject (or relay) is automatically shared.